# Torrent size taking more space on the HDD than it should

Tags: bittorrent, vuze

I have a huge torrent at hand. It should have just over 1.2 TB. It relies on a 2 "TB" HDD, that, in real size has 1.82 TB.

I say *"should"* because, in reality, it takes more space on the HDD than it should. Or at least it looks like it.

There's literally nothing else on the drive, not even hidden. There's no content in `$RECYCLE.BIN` or `System Volume Information`. There's just the one torrent's directory claiming it takes 1.2 TB, in Windows Explorer, that is.

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro.

On Properties -> General tab, I see its:

- Size: 1.21 TB
- Size on disk: 930 GB

No surprise here.

It's a GPT/NTFS formatted drive. And it says, that there's only 130 GB of space left, which does not suffice for the download.

Surprise, surprise.

The torrent client is Vuze version 5.7.5.0. I tried to download it with my favorite Transmission 2.92, but it could not handle it and crashed without any helpful error message.

I share this experience so that others could learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How this happened is a mystery to me, none-the-less, the solution was as follows:

1. Go to Options: Menu -> Tools -> Options.
2. Make sure you are in an Advanced mode: Mode -> Advanced.
3. Go to Files and check this:

   > Truncate existing files that are too large
4. Click on save button. You can close the settings by now.
5. Stop the torrent in question.
6. Force-recheck the torrent.
7. That fixed it in my case.